# Is it possible to make a type-safe collection of functions in TS?

Tags: typescript, interface

I'm writing a small library to simplify working with redux, but I got stuck with typings. 
What I am trying to do basically boils down to the following:

- parent class processes action descriptors into actions
- child class provides said descriptors

Problem is, type information defined in child is lost in the process.

Smallest test case is as follows:

```
type callable = (...args: any[]) => any
interface CallableCollection {
    [s: string]: callable
}

class Parent {
    functions: CallableCollection
    constructor() {
        this.functions = this.a;
    }
    get a(): CallableCollection {
        return {};
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    get a() {
        return {
            a: (x: string) => x,
            b: (x: number) => x,
        }
    }
}

const test = new Child();
test.a.a(5);//type error
test.functions.a(5);// no type errors
```

I could make it work properly by making class generic and supplying all needed types as type arguments, but it looks extremely lame from a class user's perspective.

Is there a way to make it work nicely in TS without supplying typings as arguments in generic class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it depends on your actual use case, but you can sometimes use [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) to take the place of generics when the particular type in question is derivable from a subclass's other properties:

```
interface CallableCollection {
  [s: string]: (...args: any[]) => any;
}

class Parent {
  functions: this["a"]; // polymorphic this and a lookup of "a"
  constructor() {
    this.functions = this.a;
  }
  get a(): CallableCollection {
    return {};
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  get a() {
    return {
      a: (x: string) => x,
      b: (x: number) => x
    };
  }
}

const test = new Child();
test.a.a(5); //type error
test.functions.a(5); // type error
```

Does that work for you?  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you. But can I make something more advanced, like functions: { callbacks: this["a"] } ?

Comment: Yes but the compiler only likes seeing `this` as a type in certain places.. you can likely make a type alias to help... e.g., `type Callbacks<T> = {callbacks: T};` and then later `class Parent {  functions: Callbacks<this["a"]>; `